# How to find the closest date from a mysql query to a specific date

Tags: python, mysql, date, datetime

I have a table in MySQL which stores dates. I also have a datetime variable called x. I want to get the closest date (from the table) to the x variable

I've been trying to do something like:

```
get_closest_date = []
query = "SELECT date_ FROM set_payment7777"
mycursor.execute(query)
for row in mycursor:
     get_closest_date.append(row)
                        
x = datetime(int(to_year_drop.get()), int(to_month_drop.get()), int(to_day_drop.get()))

cloz_dict = {abs(x).timestamp() - date.timestamp() : date for date in get_closest_date}
res = cloz_dict[min(cloz_dict.keys())]
print(res)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

any possible solution?

Comment: Edit your question and please describe the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `LIMIT` query here:

```
query = """SELECT date_
           FROM set_payment7777
           ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(date_, ?))
           LIMIT 1"""
x = datetime(int(to_year_drop.get()), int(to_month_drop.get()), int(to_day_drop.get()))
mycursor.execute(query, (x,))
date_closest = mycursor.fetchone()[0]
```

The trick here is to basically sort your table based on how close each `date_` value is to the input parameter provided.  Then, we just examine the single date closest.

Comment: this helped a bit but (I forgot to include it above) the problem is that I also use a name for each date so what I want to do is to get the closest date to the x variable based on the name. So if we have "James, 01-01-2022" we also have "James, 01-01-2021" also  "Helen, 01-01-2022" and  "Helen, 01-01-2022" I want to get 01-01-2022 and 01-01-2022